# Все возможные комбинации трех массивов с учетом порядка

Tags: python, алгоритм, комбинаторика, множества

Имеется три массива:

```
good = [1/3, 1/3, 7/15, 3/7, 3/7, 7/15]
bad  = [2/3, 2/3, 1/15, 1/7, 1/7, 1/15]
middle = [0, 0, 7/15, 3/7, 3/7, 7/15]
```

Нужно вывести все возможные комбинации этих массивов с учетом порядка с указанием откуда взят элемент:

```
[1/3, 1/3, 7/15, 3/7, 3/7, 7/15] - [good, good, good, good, good, good]
[2/3, 1/3, 7/15, 3/7, 3/7, 7/15] - [bad, good, good, good, good, good]
[0, 1/3, 7/15, 3/7, 3/7, 7/15] - [middle, good, good, good, good, good]
```

Примерно как показано выше, при этом необходимо помнить, что мы можем ставить на первое место итоговой последовательности только любой из первых элементов исходных множеств, на второе - только второй элемент и т.д.
Как это можно сделать средствами Python (может быть, с помощью itertools)? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
good = [1/3, 1/3, 7/15, 3/7, 3/7, 7/15]
bad  = [2/3, 2/3, 1/15, 1/7, 1/7, 1/15]
middle = [0, 0, 7/15, 3/7, 3/7, 7/15]
ll = [good, middle, bad]
names = ['good', 'middle', 'bad']
for i in range(3**6):
    l = []
    for j in range(6):
        r = i % 3
        l.append((ll[r][j], names[r]))
        i //= 3
    print(l)
```